# Netlogo: Assign numeric variables to different types

Tags: variables, netlogo, numeric

How to create different kind of turtles (using probabilities) in order to assign them numeric variables?
For example I have 3 different kind x-, y-, z-type (but y has 2 different kind: y1, y2 and exception is that y1 can also be z-type).
I have to assign numeric variable var1 which depends on the type (different types have different var1 value) and also var2 that depends on probabilities but exception is that z-type and y1 always has a var2 that equals to 1.
So x-type has numeric variables that always change over time but some types have numeric variables that don't change.
If I use breed then I think I can't create them according to probability and I don't need to have different variables for each breed but a plus is that I can assign them turtles-own variables. If I use if-sentence then the code will get too long and difficult to read.
Do I have to use breed or if-sentence or as I am hoping, is there a more NetLogo-ish way?

Comment: can you provide a piece of code that you've started with? it will be easier to help with something to work off of

Comment: took too long on the edit: If you don't want to give your full code, I made a super simple model in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870218/probability-for-variable-value-in-agentsets-netlogo/40873700#40873700 that you could re-purpose with your bit of code that attempts what you're going for